# An Impossible Sequence of Prime Powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of positive integers that satisfies the recurrence relation $$x_{n+1}=2x_n(x_n-1)+1$$ for all positive integers $n$. It seems impossible that every term in this sequence is a power of a prime, but I can't see a way to prove this. I have tried rewriting the terms of the sequence in terms of each other and doing several basic algebraic manipulations, but I seem to be stuck. Does anyone see a way to prove that the terms of the sequence cannot all be prime powers?

Comment: Might I ask what $x_1$ is? If I define $x_1$ as $6,$ then there is nothing to do.

Comment: Well it can be anything. In particular, it should be a power of a prime. In other words, I'm trying to show that for any choice of a positive integer $x_1$, there will be a term in the sequence that is not a power of a prime.

Comment: Is it possible to show the weaker statement that the sequence cannot consist only of primes?

Comment: Probably writing this like $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + (x_n-1)^2$ would be easier to reason about.

Comment: If $x_1=1$, then $x_n=2^0$ for all $n$. But I suppose that's not what you mean by a power of a prime....

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but I found an explicit formula for $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$ and I thought that it might be relevant:
$$x_n=2^{2^{n+1}-1}(x_0-1/2)^{2^{n+1}}+1/2$$
or, rewritten,
$$x_n=\frac{(2x_0-1)^{2^{n+1}}+1}{2}$$
Perhaps this will help you with your proof.